# Q: Linkedin Vector Assest API, Registering Multi-Part Upload - No metadata value in response

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm attempting to complete a multipart upload using [Linkedin V2 Vector Assets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api) and i've noticed that when registering the upload, the `metadata` field comes back blank in the response.

Here's the request to register the upload `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload`

```
{
    "registerUploadRequest":{
        "owner":"urn:li:organization:71736744",
        "recipes":["urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video"],
        "serviceRelationships":[
            {"identifier":"urn:li:userGeneratedContent","relationshipType":"OWNER"}
        ],
        "supportedUploadMechanism":["MULTIPART_UPLOAD"],
        "fileSize":50866165
}
```

and here is the response (removed all but one partUploadRequests object to make the response easier to read)

```
{
"value": {
    "uploadMechanism": {
        "com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MultipartUpload": {
            "partUploadRequests": [
                {
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
                    },
                    "byteRange": { "lastByte": 4194303, "firstByte": 0 },
                    "url": "https://www.linkedin.com/dms-uploads/C5605AQFnYcNsf7K5Yw/uploadedVideo?sau=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&pn=1&m=616825227&app=86804616&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1nBLJxAvwH5FI1",
                    "urlExpiresAt": 1616544717116
                } ...
            ],
            "metadata": ""
        }
    },
    "asset": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFnYcNsf7K5Yw",
    "mediaArtifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFnYcNsf7K5Yw,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:uploadedVideo)"
}
```

}

The api documentation explains that I need to use the metadata value from the register upload response to [complete the upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/vector-asset-api#complete-multi-part-upload)

I attempt making the request anyway without a value for the metadata field to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=completeMultiPartUpload` (removed all but one partUploadResponses object to make the response easier to read)

```
{
"completeMultipartUploadRequest": {
    "mediaArtifact": "urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifact:(urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFnYcNsf7K5Yw,urn:li:digitalmediaMediaArtifactClass:uploadedVideo)",
    "metadata": "",
    "partUploadResponses": [
        {
            "headers": {
                "ETag": "/ambry-video/signedId/AQGpSasdC3ezCgAAAXhcbTobXlB6_ujllr8BPUUAX4o9OgbHCxiRKoG9woM85dnGrxbUbd-5IXyMKO7syqyZXLgHFd8GQJkiMvvp1eHI9N32iJqMG-l_aFgSeXMbcqkFFcjuT22djM93dmKs_RBb58kppS3CadOPHSt5_tApCxAq0wgTfYQng3OkV_uVRdjIYftyfnHW3nF2vWz4hZBoX-YhmF6gDhXtN9dNTnU4QpHB7sGCecpjYgT8ypV-u5isvFrujHl3tl4.bin"
            },
            "httpStatusCode": 200
        } ....
    ]
}
```

}

This comes back as a 200OK without any response body which is expected.

After that I check the upload status and which comes back with a code of `SERVER_ERROR` and I'm not able to create a post with the `asset id` of the uploaded asset.
Response from checking asset status `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets/C5605AQFnYcNsf7K5Yw`

```
{
"recipes": [
    {
        "recipe": "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-video",
        "status": "SERVER_ERROR"
    }
],
"serviceRelationships": [
    {
        "relationshipType": "OWNER",
        "identifier": "urn:li:userGeneratedContent"
    }
],
"mediaTypeFamily": "VIDEO",
"created": 1616458317042,
"id": "C5605AQFnYcNsf7K5Yw",
"lastModified": 1616458454711,
"status": "ALLOWED"
```

}

Request to create a UGC post with the asset `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets`

```
{
"author": "urn:li:organization:71736744",
"lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
"specificContent": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
        "media": [
            {
                "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:C5605AQFnYcNsf7K5Yw",
                "status": "READY",
                "title": {
                    "attributes": [],
                    "text": "Sample Video Create"
                }
            }
        ],
        "shareCommentary": {
            "attributes": [],
            "text": "Some share text"
        },
        "shareMediaCategory": "VIDEO"
    }
},
"visibility": {
    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
}
```

Response to the request

```
{
"serviceErrorCode": 0,
"message": "Resource assets does not exist",
"status": 404}
```

The only thing I can think of is since I don't have a metadata value when completing the upload I'm not able to use the video asset in UGC posts. Anyone encountered a problem similar to this?

***Further Investigations***
On further investigation the example from the API docs doesn't return a `metadata` field either. So this is what I think might be happening

- I'm not uploading the file chunks correctly and the `metadata` field isn't required for completing the upload.
- The API has a bug in it which prevents it from returning the metadata field when registering a multipart upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, when using the slice method to break your file up into chunks it needs to be `file.slice(firstByte, lastByte + 1)`

It also seems that the metadata value from the register upload request isn't need to complete the upload.